# Develop custom Android Power Menu widgets

Tags: android-11

Is it possible to develop Android 11 widgets that appear on the Power Menu, **exactly** like Google Pay's card list?

So far I have discovered that there are a few useful guides on **Device Controls**, a feature that is very well suited for domotics and automation. For example the [official article on Device Controls](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/device-control) shows a fully fledged Power Menu with credit card swiping and domotics control.

I am interesting in developing a custom open source widget to browse fildelity (barcoded) cards. I have seen that the [Quick Access Wallet](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/quick-access-wallet) feature is the one to use to display payment methods as swipable cards, but I have good reasons not to follow that road. First, it is designed for payment applications who hold NFC permissions, and secondarily it will disable Google Pay as default payment application for those who use it (and those who use another payment service will experience the same problem).

And Device Controls are templated and suited to be displayed in the Google Home's designated area.

So I'd like to ask if there are Android APIs to implement a fully customized widget to appear in the power menu. Of course I can **kindly** ask user for any permission necessary.

I start from the assumption that Google Pay itself is an application developed on top of Android framework, and has little to no special permission/policy-exception/whitelist from the OS, along with other payment applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to ask if there are Android APIs to implement a fully customized widget to appear in the power menu

Not in Android 11, at least in terms of public APIs.

> I start from the assumption that Google Pay itself is an application developed on top of Android framework, and has little to no special permission/policy-exception/whitelist from the OS, along with other payment applications.

That is a very generous assumption. IMHO, do not assume that you can do anything that is being done by Google or the manufacturer of the device you are trying.